# android custom view in expandablelistview with adapter goes nuts

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

I have a serious problem with a custom view i use in an expandableListView. I use an adapter that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter. The custom view changes its state depending on if it is being consulted or modifying. The state change involves animation and show/hide of ui parts.
The problem is that even thought i let only two views, when i click on the second view i order to make it change its state, the adapter calls the getViewGroup fo the two views but systematically inverting the corresponding model data ids.. .witch makes the ui to animate again...
I precise that i don't use the viewholder pattern since the custom view has its own internal references to the controls to be updated.
Any idea would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

i found out the solution, everytime the model changes i called notifyDataChanged() which makes the entire listview to be redrawn